# Why does this preg_replace call return NULL?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Why does this call return NULL?
Is the regex wrong? With the `test` input it doesn't return NULL.
The docs say NULL indicates an error but what error could it be?

```
$s = hex2bin('5b5d202073205b0d0a0d0a0d0a0d0a20202020202020203a');
// $s = 'test';
$s = preg_replace('/\[\](\s|.)*\]/s', '', $s);
var_dump($s);

// PHP 7.2.10-1+0~20181001133118.7+stretch~1.gbpb6e829 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2018 13:31:18) ( NTS )
```

Comment: What do you need to do here? Your `$s` has no second `]`  hence there is no match. Also, `(\s|.)*` is not necessary, it is bad, just use `.*` (`preg_replace("/\[].*]/s", "", $s)`)

Comment: It's also a good idea to use single quotes around a regexp rather than double quotes. Otherwise you run the risk that a regexp escape sequence will be processed as a string escape sequence.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm primarily wondering why this returns NULL. If there's no match the input should just be returned shouldn't it?

Comment: It return `NULL` if the regexp is invalid.

Comment: What's the point of `(\s|.)`.  `.` matches `\s` already..

Comment: Your initial string is not `'test'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is causing [**catastrophic backtracking**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and causing PHP regex engine to fail. You can use [`preg_last_error()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) to check this.

```
$r = preg_replace("/\[\](\s|.)*\]/s", "", $s);
if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) {
    print 'Backtrack limit was exhausted!';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Backtrack limit was exhausted!
```

You are getting `NULL` return value from `preg_replace` due to this error. As per [PHP doc of `preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or **NULL if an error occurred**.

---

**Fix:** You don't need `(\s|.)` when using `s` modifier (**DOTALL**). since dot matches any character including newline when using `s` modifier.

You should just use this regex:

```
$r = preg_replace('/\[\].*?\]/s', "", $s);
echo preg_last_error();
//=> 0
```